# When modal tabindex="-1" cant write in another modal thats inside it?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, tabindex

I have one modal with `tabindex="-1"` and a button in that modal which opens another modal that has text inputs in which u can not write unless i remove `tabindex="-1"` in first modal.

Is there any way to solve this? I tried adding `tabindex` to second modal too but no use.

Comment: anyone knows a solution?

Comment: can you create a www.bootply.com demonstrating the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem and ended up removing the `tabindex="-1"`